# Criar Lista de actions já passando os parâmetros e depois executá-las conforme parâmetros passados

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, actions

Queria saber se existe a possibilidade de criar uma lista de Actions já passando seus parâmetros para execução, pois os número que vou passar para a execução das mesma pode ser variável, então gostaria de guardar essas aActions já com seus parâmetros para depois só executa-las todas de uma vez.

Segue um exemplo:

```
    public class Program
{
    private static List<Task> ListActions = new List<Task>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExecuteMethod();
        ExecuteListDeActions();
    }

    private static void ExecuteMethod()
    {
        int loop = 10;


        while (loop > 0)
        {
            int valor1 = new Random().Next();
            int valor2 = new Random().Next();
            int valor3 = new Random().Next();

            ListActions.Add(new Task(() => MinhaAction(valor1, valor2, valor3)));

            loop--;
        }
    }

    private async static Task<int> MinhaAction(int valor1, int valor2, int valor3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Numero 1: " + valor1);
        Console.WriteLine("Numero 2: " + valor2);
        Console.WriteLine("Numero 3: " + valor3);
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");

        return valor1 + valor2 + valor3;
    }

    private async static void ExecuteListDeActions()
    {
        foreach(var a in ListActions)
        {
            a.Start();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Não é duplicada meu amigo, a minha pergunta é simples e objetiva, eu gostaria de criar uma lista de Actions já passando os parâmetros para elas e depois só executá-las entende? E não passar os valores dos parâmetros assim que realizar o loop na lista. Entende ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que no teu caso seja melhor utilizar Task, já que você tem interesse em executados todas de uma vez.

[Referência](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class Program
{
    private List<Task> ListActions = new List<Task>();

    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rand = new Random();
        int valor1 = rand.Next();
        int valor2 = rand.Next();
        int valor3 = rand.Next();
        Task t = Task.Run(() => MinhaAction(valor1, valor2, valor3));
        ListActions.Add(t);
    }

    private int MinhaAction(int valor1, int valor2, int valor3)
    {
        return valor1 + valor2 + valor3;
    }

    private void ExecuteListDeActions()
    {
        Task.WaitAll(ListActions.ToArray());
        foreach (Task t in ListActions)
            Console.WriteLine("Task {0} Status: {1}", t.Id, t.Status);

        Console.WriteLine("T: {0}", ListActions.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Marcus, desse jeito o Invoke pede para passar os parâmetros para ela, mudei o código da minha pergunta, de uma olhada.

Comment: Acredito que no teu caso seja melhor utilizar Task, já que você tem interesse em executados todas de uma vez. Alterei a resposta.

Comment: Ok , vou testar essa solução amigo, já volto para dar a resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: Pra que serve o Task.WaitAll(ListActions.ToArray()); ?

Comment: Garante que todas as tarefas tenham sido concluídas. https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: não consegui executar essas tasks com o valor que realmente é passado como parâmetro, por algum motivo o meu retorno acaba sendo todos os números iguais.. vou editar meu código do jeito que fiz pra você dar uma olhada.

Comment: -------------------
Numero 1: 1020216779
Numero 2: 1020216779
Numero 3: 1020216779
-------------------
-------------------
Numero 1: 1020216779
Numero 2: 1020216779
Numero 3: 1020216779
-------------------
-------------------
Numero 1: 1790744707
Numero 2: 1790744707
Numero 3: 1790744707

Comment: Sai os números duplicados, consegue testar o código que modifiquei para você ver ? sendo que todos os parâmetros são números randomicos, ele está executando a rotina com os mesmos números.

Comment: A forma como você está gerando o Random que tá errada. Tente utilizar o que coloquei na resposta.

Comment: Perfeito, isso deu certo. Mais uma pergunta, vi que os métodos são executados tudo juntos, ou seja, todos ao mesmo tempo, teria como usar um await nessa situação? para esperar uma task terminar e depois executar a outra. ?É a primeira vez que utilizo task.

Comment: Fiz assim e deu certo, está correto ?

Comment: foreach(var a in ListActions)
            {
                a.Start();
                a.Wait();
            }